# Razor handle session state timeout on post

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, session-cookies

I use session state with cookie in my razor web app
The doc said the session is restored in the server if the cookie has timed out

> If a cookie is received for an expired session, a new session is created that uses the same session cookie.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state)

It works when the cookie has timed out (or I delete it) and I reload the page, the state is preserved

But the issue is that I use a lot of Ajax to do partial page load and the state is not preserved when I call a POST handler by ajax

Is there a way to have the same behaviour for POST as for GET in order the restore the session state ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure if my test result matched yours...

I have a razor web app and here's my view and my action code.

```
@page
@model WebAppRazor.Pages.Clients.IndexModel
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@{
}

<div>this is clients/index</div>
<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' href='/Clients/Create'>New Client</a>

<button onclick="postdata()">Abc</button>
<input type="text" id="sessionInfo"></input>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        function postdata() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/clients/index?handler=Abc',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                },
                data: {
                    id: "asdf"
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    // alert('Success!');
                    console.info(data);
                    $('#sessionInfo').val(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}

public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public const string SessionKeyName = "_Name";
    public const string SessionKeyAge = "_Age";

    public void OnGet()
    {
        var sessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;
        
        
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName)))
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "UserA");
            HttpContext.Session.SetInt32(SessionKeyAge, 18);
        }
        var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
        var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge).ToString();
    }

    
    public IActionResult OnPostAbc(string id)
    {
        var sessionId = HttpContext.Session.Id;
        var name = HttpContext.Session.GetString(SessionKeyName);
        var age = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32(SessionKeyAge).ToString();
        return new JsonResult(name + age);
    }

}
```

Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
...
...
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.MapRazorPages();
```

And this is my test result.

[image]